# Shall. I use a preposition here?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence

which one is correct?

> We had a very small marriage ceremony where only close relatives and friends were invited.

Or

> We had a very small marriage ceremony where only close relatives and friends were invited to.

Comment: _What possesses people_ to upvote a question 10-year-old native speakers should be able to answer? It's important to know the answer, of course, and I'm not trying to insult someone who's just learning the language. But ELU is one of the few sites for 'linguists ...'.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence reads okay to me; I would not use the second sentence.

But I would suggest this rewording:

*We had a very small marriage ceremony to which only close relatives and friends were invited.*

Or better yet, to avoid switching to the passive voice:

*We had a very small marriage ceremony to which we invited only close relatives and friends.*